# How to make responsive layout in Android Which should look good in all size mobile and tab also in landscape portraite view

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape-portrait

I am developing an Android application and layout design is not looking good in tab but
the app looks great in 4"inch, 5"inch screen and in portrait mode but when I switch to landscape mode the design is not looking good. What should I do to make my design look good in both landscape & portrait modes?

Comment: what are the size of image background

Comment: i don't have any background image.. but i have 3 small images of size 70*50. in portrait mode these image i kept one after other when i switch to landscape all 3 images are coming left side right side it is showing blank where it not looks good

Comment: Use weight in your xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `layout-land` directory then create and put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory. And also create layouts depending upon height or width. For example- `layout-w480dp, layout-w720dp or layout-h800dp or layout-h1280dp.`

Answer (score 1):

```
 You have to make app in this size format in android 

  Several Kinds of Size of app Declaration

 http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

 http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

  image icon size are 

  1:-36*36 dp
  2:-44*44 dp
  3:-72*72 dp
  4:-96*96 dp
  5:-144*144 dp if you want to make big image in tab
```

Image size of background

```
512*512
1024*768

  what size are perfect in your Device that you have to use.
```

also depends on device focus.

Comment: i have told size Depend on Flexibility of Device